# If/Then/Else in SAS Not Working

Tags: if-statement, sas

Struggling to get this If/Then/Else statement not working. I have two columns: Variable and Value. Variable has the name of the variable and Value has all the potential codes that could be associated with that Variable.

Example:

```
Variable     Value
Gender         F
Gender         M
```

I want to create a field called "Flag" and if the value isn't among the list of values, it should flag that field; otherwise, leave that field blank

```
data Want;
length 
Variable $40.
Value $40.
Flag $8.;
set Have (keep = Variable Value);
if (Variable = 'Gender' and Value ^= 'M') then Flag = 'UnkCode'; else Flag="";
if (Variable = 'Gender' and Value ^= 'F') then Flag = 'UnkCode'; else  Flag="";
if (Variable = 'Gender' and Value ^= 'O') then Flag = 'UnkCode'; else Flag="";
if (Variable = 'Gender' and Value ^= 'U') then Flag = 'UnkCode'; else Flag="";
run;
quit;
```

The dataset I'm using has only has two values for Gender: F and M. For whatever reason, the flag field in both lines has "UnkCode"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because the last of your conditions will always match for your dataset.  Interesting language though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be, possibly, a little more clear: your if statements are evaluated sequentially.

So for your first observation, Flag will be initially set to "", as ('M' = 'M'). However, Flag is then overwritten by your subsequent if statements, and as ('M' ^= 'F'), Flag is overwritten, and takes the value 'UnkCode'.

In addition to Keni's use of an in statement (which is better than the code I am about to suggest), you could also do the following (which may help you understand if statements better).

```
if (Variable = 'Gender' and Value = 'M') then Flag = "";
else if (Variable = 'Gender' and Value = 'F') then Flag = "";
else if (variable = 'Gender' and Value = 'O') then Flag = "";
else if (Variable = 'Gender' and Value = 'U') then Flag = "";
else if (Variable = 'Gender') then Flag = 'UnkCode';
```

I might also suggest that instead of having a variable named 'Variable', with a value of 'Gender', you simply have a variable named 'Gender' with a value of 'F' or 'M'. While there are certainly specific circumstances in which you would not want to create your dataset this way, they are relatively few and far between.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I actually have different things in the variable Field ("Gender" "Race" "Ethnicity" etc) and was hoping to do a different if/then statement for each. If I just continue to repeat the if/then, every field in the "Flag" column gets input as "UnkCode" (which makes sense, given your explanation that it's bing overwritten). Any idea how I can remedy this? (my apologies for not putting it in earlier; I was hoping to just expand any given code to the rest of the data set)

Comment: Good answer, it's better to explain what's wrong with the original code rather than just saying, 'that was wrong, this is right'.

Answer (score 4):

I put all the IF conditions in one statement and it worked.

```
data Want;
      length Variable $40. Value $40. Flag $8.;
      set Have (keep = Variable Value);
      If (Variable = 'Gender' and Value in ('F','M','O','U')) then Flag =" "; 
         else Flag = 'UnkCode'; 
run;
quit;
```

For multiple variables to flag for... this should work.

```
data Want;
    length Variable $40. Value $40. Flag $8.;
    set Have (keep = Variable Value);
    Flag = 'UnkCode';
    if (Variable = 'Gender' and Value in ('F','M','O','U')) then Flag =" "; 
    else if (Variable = 'Race' and Value in ('B','A')) then Flag =" ";  
run;
quit;
```

Comment: This works! But I'm still struggling with something: I actually have different things in the variable Field ("Gender" "Race" "Ethnicity" etc) and was hoping to do a different if/then statement for each. If I just continue to repeat the if/then in the format you provided, every field in the "Flag" column gets input as "UnkCode". (my apologies for not putting it in earlier; I was hoping to just expand any given code to the rest of the data set)

Comment: N/M! When I do the else if between each line, it works great. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Yes, I added additional code for the new variables. Declaring the Flag as unkcode first and then modifying the value to blank after checking works.